# What is the best method to hide <img> on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

in my html I have four `img` tags which I want to hide on mobile devices and I'm looking for best method to do it without downloading them on mobile. 
I found out that using `display:none` in CSS doesn't prevent browser from downloading image, also I know how to use `srcset` attribute to source shuffling based on media queries but I don't know if it's posible to use it to hide content based on media queries.
Does anyone know how to do it properly ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way might be to not add values to the `src` attributes until you've figured out what the device is. Load the elements with the class identifying the device:

```
<img class="desktop" data-src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
```

Then once you've identified the device, add the URL in the data attribute to `src` for each affected image:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.desktop');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].src = images[i].dataset.src;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3o80bqao/2/)

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use the images as background images in DIVs and only include those with a media query on larger screens using a mobile-first approach.